# MUI Slider with restricted values but equal spacing

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am using my own marks and displaying them on the slider using [restricted values](https://mui.com/components/slider/#restricted-values) however the spacing is not ideal. How can I keep my own min/max/custom markers but have them be equally spaced on the slider?

Currently:

```
2-2.8-4-5.6---8---11----16
```

Desired:

```
2--2.8--4--5.6--8--11--16
```

```
<Box sx={{ width: 365 }}>
  <Slider
    aria-label="aperture"
    defaultValue={8}
    step={null}
    valueLabelDisplay="auto"
    marks={marksAperture[camera][0].settings} //2, 2.8, 4, 5.6, 8, 11, 16
    min={marksAperture[camera][0].minStop} //2
    max={marksAperture[camera][0].maxStop} //16
    onChange={this.handleApertureChange}
    sx={{
      "& .MuiSlider-markLabel": {
        fontSize: "10px",
      },
    }}
  />
</Box>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is achievable by using a dictionary to map between the internal values of the `Slider` (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7) to the scaled values (2, 2.8, 4, 5.6, 8, 11, 16).

You also need to add a `scale` callback to transform the value before it's displayed in the tooltip:

```
function calculateValue(value) {
  switch (value) {
    case 1:
      return 2;
    case 2:
      return 2.8;
    case 3:
      return 4;
    case 4:
      return 5.6;
    case 5:
      return 8;
    case 6:
      return 11;
    case 7:
      return 16;
    default:
      return 0;
  }
}

const marks = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7].map((value) => ({
  value,
  label: calculateValue(value)
}));
```

There is a small issue when using restricted values. If you drag the thumb a little bit but not enough to jump to the next or previous mark, the `change` handler still fires repeatedly. To prevent that, you can use controlled mode and update the state only if the value is changed:

```
const [value, setValue] = React.useState(null);

return (
  <Slider
    defaultValue={8}
    step={null}
    value={value}
    onChange={(_, newValue) => {
      if (newValue !== value) {
        console.log(calculateValue(newValue));
        setValue(newValue);
      }
    }}
    valueLabelDisplay="auto"
    marks={marks}
    scale={calculateValue}
    min={1} //2
    max={7} //16
  />
);
```

[image: Codesandbox Demo]

Comment: thanks @nearhuscarl do we need `scale={calculateValue}`? it works without it. the new marks seem to be creating the desired scale now.

Comment: @sn4ke if you don't add the `scale` callback, the tooltip will display the internal values of the `Slider` before scale (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7), which is not a desirable outcome.